# Windows - run Wamp service as system/user - privilege of scheduled task

Tags: php, windows, windows-services, wamp, scheduled-tasks

Environment: windows, wamp service, php, scheduled task.

To having access for some resources, I configured wamp service to running as user `User_A` (admin group).

I have a protected folder Protected_Folder: only users in admin group have full access.

I have a scheduled task who execute everyday with `User_A` account. It is configured to run even if `User_A` is logged out: a `.bat` file:

```
C:/path/to/php.exe my_script.php
```

However, the scheduled task do not have privilege to create/write a file/folder in `Protected_Folder` if the user is logged out.

Comment: Side Note: I dont see why you run WampServer as an `other user` as you say that user is in the Admin Group. What does this achieve except complexity, as if you get hacked the hack will still be hacking as an Administrator

Comment: I might have multi users then I have the protected folder just to prevent ordinary user access. I'm working with Microsoft Crt Magasin, I tried but I'm not successful to access my crt if wamp service run as system (even I did import my crt to my machine but not to particular user). So I have to run wamp service as user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but I do not know if I solved it by a combination of circumstance or because I have found the right solution.

So I edited my batch file to open a page instead of launching directly the PHP script

```
@echo off
start "" http://localhost/path/to/my_script.php
```

And it finally worked, I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works like a charm. But after the scheduled task, my navigator (Firefox) is blocking. It do appear in the list of processus of windows tasks manager, then I have to force tasks manager to close it. Do you have any ideas about this pb?

Comment: @Anh-TuanMai I also use Firefox and never had this problem. But you can try to add `taskkill /im firefox.exe /f` to your batch file to close all firefox process. If you just want to kill the last tab of firefox you should use VBScript instead (see stackoverflow.com/questions/32776448)